# Java & Selenium Web Scraping click button doesent work

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

**Hello guys,**

I am currently using Java Selenium to code a script that will automatically click and fill types for me. I have written a code line which does not work. I want it to click on a button, but it does not do this. When I run the application the bot scrolls down to the button but does not click on the button. When you click on the button a new page should be opened. I do not know what I did wrong can someone help me? Thanks for any answer!

**My Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    
    driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
    
    driver.get("https://deutsche-giganetz.de/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div/div/nav/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[8]/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/a")).click();
    
}

}
```

**My error code:**
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 108.0,
moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20221208122842, moz:debuggerAddress: 127.0.0.1:38233,
moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.32.0, moz:headless: false, moz:platformVersion: 10.0, moz:processID: 15732, moz:profile: C:\Users\OKANAY~1\AppData\L..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000,  moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, moz:windowless: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp:
ws://127.0.0.1:38233/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 85.0, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability:  false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss    and notify}

```
Element: [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (dae2e314-a112-48de-ada9-bd6ffce54a94)]
-> xpath: `/html/body/main/div[8]/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/a]
Session ID: dae2e314-a112-48de-ada9-bd6ffce54a94
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to do it with "findelement css selector" instead of "findelement xpath". I couldn't implement it via a link because there are several buttons called "Order Now". I did a lot of research but didn't find anything else.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should always set timeouts for loading the page, it is also advisable to check the end of the javascript loading, then find out if the element is clickable, and then call the click method

```
Duration pageLoadTimeout = Duration.ofMinutes(1);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(pageLoadTimeout);

driver.get("https://deutsche-giganetz.de/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, pageLoadTimeout);

// waiting for loading all page
wait.until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver)
                .executeScript("return document.readyState")
                .equals("complete"));

// By.className alternative By.xpath (for example use "uk-button btn-white") 
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.className("uk-button btn-white"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
button.click();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your helpful answer. But I still have one question. You meant that I should address the button with class name and that the button should be clicked. But on the page there are 4 buttons with the same name, and I want to have one of them clicked. That's why the script breaks and doesn't work as you showed it.

Comment: If I use:
 WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[8]/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/a"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
button.click();

I get an error code and the Script is doing nothing.